# Migrating an existing DotnetCore WebAPI into Azure Serverless functions

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi

We have been migrating with Serverless computing for some time now. Recently we decided to check if it made sense to convert an existing dotnetcore WebAPI into a set of azure serverless functions.

Existing Implementation:- The existing DotnetCore WebAPI tech stack was as under

- Database First Entity Framework core with SQL Azure
- The internal code was layered into BL, DL with C#
- JWT token authentication
- Visual Studio 2019

Our “New” implementations as our decisions were influenced by “how much rework” we will need to do.

Comment: What is your reason to moving to Azure Serverless functions? There are few cross cutting concerns like authentictaion/authorization which are not direct plugable which is there in Dotnet Core web API? Also, it is very specific to **my applicatoin**, I saw that app service plan had better performance compared to Azure consumption plan? You can cross validate for yours. Based on your requirement and fitment you can take a decision.

Comment: @user1672994 cost-cutting is also one of the factors

Comment: what are your cross cutting concerns which are leading to change in technology stack?

Comment: @user1672994 microservices architecture  and server less